# Use spray paint to make mask for pre-sensitised board?

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I'm about to etch my first simple board for a project. I have a pre-sensitised board that (as I understand the process) you expose to UV light, then develop the board in a sodium hydroxide solution, then etch. The UV light will negatively affect the protective lacquer and developing it after exposing washes away the lacquer, making the board ready to etch.

I got the lye and I got sodium persulfate for the etching but I did not have any transparent paper as I thought I did! And it's impossible for me to get a hold of it in time (= this weekend, I live far from the city and it's a small one and I haven't found any place that stocks it so I have to order online and that's sometime next week I'd get it at the fastest).

So I am looking for an alternative solution. What I am considering is printing the design to regular paper, cut out a mask carefully from this paper and place it over the board and paint a mask on. Spray paint most likely, then in theory I would have a UV mask.

Anyone see any flaws in this plan?

Comment: I believe you can also get some sort of spray which kinda transparentizes regular paper ... I don't know how well it works or much else about it though ...

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* transparent paper. You only need a mask that *blocks* the part where you want copper and *passes* UV where you want to etch the copper away.  If you use ordinary paper, it just means that you must use a significantly longer exposure time to properly expose the board.  And you must be sure that the black areas are sufficiently opaque to *block* the UV during the longer exposure.

But, no matter what you use, you should at least take a sample strip of the board and run an exposure test to see how long the exposure should be and what is the tolerance for exposure time, distance, brightness, etc. etc.

As @brhans suggested, you could also experiment with making the paper more transparent. Perhaps soaking in vegetable oil from the kitchen or even water(?)

Unless you have a very large and simple pattern, trying to cut out a "stencil" to spray paint the mask seems extraordinarily unlikely to me.

Comment: Well I happened to find a bread board, so if nothing else I should be able to get it together. It's a very simple and small circuit controlling 3 pots for a TIG pedal.

Answer (score 0):

I usually print the design on a normal paper using a laser printer. With white spirit you can soak the paper and make it semi-transparent. This works well enough to get good results. You might need some extra time with the UV light though.

Comment: Does this work with inkjets too?

Comment: I don't know. My experience with inkjet printers is that the ink will smudge when it comes in contact water, so I doubt it will work well... If you have prototype board, then I would use that. Especially with such a simple circuit.