# Can spray paint or a marker block UV for solder mask/resist?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, solder-mask, uv

I am planning to make a PCB and putting solder mask on it but I don't have my own laser printer to print the transparency for the mask. I do, however, live near a printing shop with a laser printer who can print glossy/photo paper but not transparencies. So I am thinking if I can use spray paint or a marker to "draw" on empty transparencies by using a soldering paste stencil as a guide. I have seen [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/265946/use-spray-paint-to-make-mask-for-pre-sensitised-board) question being answered but its not what I'm looking for. So will spray paint or a marker block UV for solder mask/resist so that the pads won't dry?

Comment: I've used an inkjet printer. It works very well.

Comment: @LeonHeller The inkjet transparencies are WAY more expensive than the lazer ones like 50 injet transparencies cost as much as 200 laser transparencies.

Comment: They work a lot better, though, I've found.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, black markers and black paint CAN block UV for photo-sensitive mask exposure. However there are two critical considerations....

1. IMAGING  How are you going to create the design?  For one-off crude patterns, you could manually draw the pattern with a black marker.  Not very accurate or repeatable, but maybe that is not required for your (undisclosed) project.  Spraying through a solder mask would seem problematic causing paint to remain in tiny holes, rendering the mask faulty.  Doesn't sound appealing to me. YMMV????
2. OPACITY vs. EXPOSURE  Unknown how UV opaque the marker or paint is? Always recommended to make "test strip" experiments where you work out all of the variables (including opacity and also photo sensitivity and exposure light strength, etc, etc.  Before attempting to make a real board.

Comment: Well, thank you for the answer! For the soldering paste stencil(you called it a solder mask and im assuming you meant stencil) I won't be using any expensive one. I might make it from a soda can like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWUJtmgh55M) so I can throw it away and make a new one anyways if it become clogged with paint.